# My Coordinate Reference System listing is in the wrong language

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, internationalization

[image]

I just installed QGIS Desktop 2.0.1 on a desktop (Windows 8-64).

All the menus are in English-US (as they should be), but the CRS listings -- when I try to change them for a project are a layer -- are in French.  I fiddled with changing the language parameters in Settings | Options | Locale, but no matter what I do, the CRS listings still come up in French.

You can see in the attached image that the menus are in English, but the CRS names are in French (i.e., "Projection conique conforme" rather than "Conformal conic projection").

Any idea what I need to do to fix this?

Dave

Answer (score 2):

That's not wrong: These projections are contributed by IGNF, and only useful for France and its dependencies.

All EPSG projections should be in English as you might expect. Even if you don't have English locale.

Comment: Where are the EPSG projections?

I could only find a handful of EPSG CRS definitions in Dufour. As I remember, QGIS Lisboa had dozens of EPSG and North American CRS definitions.

None of the ones I used for older projects in Wroclaw and Lisboa are visible in Dufour.

Comment: Then your installation must be broken somewhere, or Windows 8 needs special treatment. Can you try installing the 32-bit version?