# Predefined Coordinate Systems missing in QGIS 2

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-2

in QGis 1.8 were lots of predefined coordinate systems (national projections). Where have they all gone in qgis 2.0? I specifically need the Gauß-Krüger-Projections Zone 1 to 5.

Is there any plugin to load those coordinate systems?

Comment: Most of them should still be there (perhaps a corrupted install?). On the off chance that you do need to add it back in as a local change, see http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#sec-custom-projections

Comment: I reinstalled the 64-bit version, there is no gauss-kruger-koordinate system predefined

Comment: You're sure? In my 64 bit version they are available (http://i.imgur.com/ZkQ5uSL.png). Alternatively you could just define them manually (easy way is to import a GK projected layer and save the incorporated projection)

Answer (score 1):

I was also missing most of the CRS list in my 2.0.1 Dufour install.  Based on Andre's response, I had a look at the postinstall.log files.  For the record I'm running:

- Windows 7 SP1
- QGIS 2.0.1 x86_64 installed on my E: drive (QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.0.1-3-Setup-x86_64.exe)
- QGIS 1.8.0 previously installed (also on E: drive; no issues with CRS)
- User is local admin

QGIS 2.0.1 postinstall.log on E: drive:

```
Synchronizing CRS database with GDAL/PROJ definitions.
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
Loading epsg.wkt
0 WKTs loaded
CRS update (inserted:0 updated:0 deleted:3631 errors:0)
No CRS updates were necessary.
```

Uninstalled 2.0.1 from E: drive and reinstalled in default location on C: (QGIS 1.8.0 untouched):

```
Synchronizing CRS database with GDAL/PROJ definitions.
Loaded 465/466 from C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\gcs.csv
Loaded 3790/3831 from C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\pcs.csv
Loaded 147/148 from C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\vertcs.csv
Loaded 61/62 from C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\compdcs.csv
Loaded 129/130 from C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\geoccs.csv
Loading epsg.wkt
Loading esri_extra.wkt
5044 WKTs loaded
CRS update (inserted:1248 updated:986 deleted:1 errors:0)
2234 CRSs updated.
```

Success!  My CRSs are back.  I hope this helps someone (especially a developer)!

Comment: Did you get any error messages before the part you quoted? See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87477/qgis-gisbase-specify-location with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing CRS like EPSG:31467, the Installation of QGIS is broken at some stage. We had several similar cases recently:

[My Coordinate Reference System listing is in the wrong language](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79407/my-coordinate-reference-system-listing-is-in-the-wrong-language)

[Saving a gml layer does not change coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80266/saving-a-gml-layer-does-not-change-coordinates)

but have not yet found the reason for it.

Have a look at the postinstall.log file (for Windows standalone) or etc\var\log\setup.log.full (for OSGEo4W). It should tell you why the CRS update process failed.

Please add Operating System and the installer you used to your question.

For 32-bit standalone, the postinstall.log of mine contains starting line 174:

```
Synchronizing CRS database with GDAL/PROJ definitions.
Loaded 465/466 from C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\gcs.csv
Loaded 3790/3831 from C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\pcs.csv
Loaded 147/148 from C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\vertcs.csv
Loaded 61/62 from C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\compdcs.csv
Loaded 129/130 from C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\share\gdal\geoccs.csv
Loading epsg.wkt
Loading esri_extra.wkt
5044 WKTs loaded
CRS update (inserted:1248 updated:986 deleted:1 errors:0)
2234 CRSs updated.
```

OSGeo4W reports at the end of setup.full.log the same entries:

Unfortunately, OSGEO4W64 does not give detailed output for me, but contains the usual CRS.

See also [Problem installing QGIS Valmeira on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92908/problem-installing-qgis-valmeira-on-windows-7-professional-64-bit) and the ticket

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9409 and probably also https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10001